# How to assign variables to a vector

Tags: r, variables, vector, variable-assignment

I have a csv file with 28 columns and 1000 rows.

I want to assign a specific set of columns to a vector, in order to analyze that vector in further steps.

The question is:

> How can I define the columns to be stored in the vector?

What I have done is:

```
carbo2 <- carbo[,-4,-5,]
#or
carbo2 <- carbo[,c(-4,-5),]
```

In some cases, those command lines work almost well. But, when I print those vectors, I find that some columns, that I do not want, were assigned.

Comment: If you want them as a vector then `c(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)`...?

Comment: Or to exclude them: `iris[, -c(4,5)]`

Comment: May worth reading about ranges and subset in R ... carbo[,-(4:5)] should do, there's nothing like 3 dimension subset for a vector, a vector has only one dimension, I assume you're talking about a dataframe here.

Comment: What is `carbo[,-4,-5,]` supposed to mean? What are you trying to do exactly? It's much easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample input and desired output.